# Facing issue while retrieving the user subscriptions for windows strore app through api

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, azure-active-directory

I have registered an app in the partner center, and integrated my app to the azure ad application, when i try to add the subscriptions to the user or get the subscriptions of the user by following the below url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user, i am getting the AuthenticationTokenInvalid error

i have called the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token api by passing my client id and client secret as described in the above link provided, i am able to retrieve the access token for the https://onestore.microsoft.com 
and when i try to get the subscriptions which i have already added through my partner center as add on through the https://purchase.mp.microsoft.com/v8.0/b2b/recurrences/query api by passing my b2b key, i am getting the below error

when i generated the access token with the resource as https://onestore.microsoft.com i am getting the below error

{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "data": [],
    "details": [],
    "innererror": {
        "code": "AuthenticationTokenInvalid",
        "data": [
            "ObjectId is required."
        ],
        "details": [],
        "message": "Authentication token supplied is invalid"
    },
    "message": "The client is not authorized to perform the requested operation.",
    "source": "PurchaseFD"
}
 and when i generated the access token with resource as https://onestore.microsoft.com/b2b/keys/create/purchase
i am getting the below error

{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "data": [],
    "details": [],
    "innererror": {
        "code": "AuthenticationTokenInvalid",
        "data": [
            "ObjectId is required."
        ],
        "details": [],
        "message": "Authentication token supplied is invalid"
    },
    "message": "The client is not authorized to perform the requested operation.",
    "source": "PurchaseFD"
}

i have followed the same as mentioned in the above pasted link, but not able to determine what went wrong

Comment: I'm not sure where the issue is. Please re-check the [Manage product entitlements from a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service#step-1-configure-an-application-in-azure-ad) document to see if you have missed someone step.

Comment: From the error message, we could know that you have not specified the 'ObjectId'. You could find some tools to parse your token to see if the 'ObjectId' is there.

Comment: Besides, `Depending on which methods you want to call in the Microsoft Store collection API or purchase API, you must create either two or three different tokens. Each access token is associated with a different audience URI (these are the same URIs that you previously added to the "identifierUris" section of the Azure AD application manifest).` Please check if you configured it correctly.

Comment: Hi Xavier,I have already followed the doc pasted.For the identifieruris i am not able to add the indentifer uri's to my azure ad application manifest file, i am getting hostNameNotOnVerifiedDomain error while i am trying to add these entries

Comment: With my testing, I could edit the manifest successfully. To help you diagnose this issue, please provide the detailed reproducible steps. Or if possible, you could try to create a new azure ad application.

Comment: I am trying to call the microsoft purchase api, before that i have generated the access token with resource as https://onestore.microsoft.com and i am able to get the access token, but using that access token when i am trying to invoke the subscription api, with b2b key which i have copied from my partner center, i am getting this error             
 {"code":"InternalServerError"{"code":"InternalAadAuthenticationError","data":["B2Bkey"],"details":[],"message":"InternalerrorduringAADauthentication."},"message":"Aninternalservererroroccurredwhileprocessingtheoperation.","source":"PurchaseFD"}

Comment: Is there any other way instead of copying the b2b key from partner center, i have seen there are some .net libraries to get the store id key(b2b key) but i am looking for some java code to get the store id key so that i can pass to the subscription api